# Moving to build tools 1.3.0 broke our build with proguard enabled

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

Our background is that we have turned off obfuscation[-dontobfuscate] in proguard. And in our build.gradle file we have minifyEnabled to true. Everything was working fine until we switched to 1.3.0 build tools

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

Now, the build breaks because it cant find the mapping.txt file which is only supposed to be generated if the obfuscation is turned on. Here is the exception I get

```
Execution failed for task ':app_name:uploadArchives'.
    10:49:57.642 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not publish configuration 'archives'
    10:49:57.642 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Cannot publish artifact 'app.map (app_name:1.2.3)’ (/Users/build_area/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt) as it does not exist.
```

So for some reason uploadArchives thinks that obfuscation is turned on. Also, to point out if I turn on obfuscation things work fine and build works fine.

Did something break or am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: This does not seem to be related to the android-maven-plugin

Comment: Can you post your entire `build.gradle`?